# ASP.NET MVC - Login Success, but userId returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity

I'm using the basic mvc-5 login method and just trying to access the userid on success

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            returnUrl = CheckUserRoleAndRedirect();
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Here `string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();` userId return null for the 1st time but next time it works fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After logging in (and redirecting to another page), the `IPrincipal.IIdentity` should be a `ClaimsIdentity`. You can try this:

```
var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
if (claimsIdentity != null)
{
    // the principal identity is a claims identity.
    // now we need to find the NameIdentifier claim
    var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    if (userIdClaim != null)
    {
        var userIdValue = userIdClaim.Value;
    }
}
```

This should work for you. If you still unable to get the id then you have to redirect to another page before the server will write the authentication cookie to the browser.

**Or Another approach is this :**

```
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
       ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);
       string UserId = user.Id;
       returnUrl = CheckUserRoleAndRedirect();
       return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to use identity to get userid before redirection?

Comment: `string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();` is something wrong in this?

Comment: No. This is perfectly fine but you will get id after redirecting only

Answer (score 6):

Once called, SignInAsync creates a AuthenticationResponseGrant and details are not available in User.Identity until next call.

However you can get around this by accessing AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity directly:

```
var Grant = SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant;
string UserId = Grant.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Of course there is no need to map `Grant` however it makes the code more readable.

Comment: This is fantastic. Reliably allows you to access the ClaimsIdentity before redirect occurs. Nice one!